# Print toString from different classes

Tags: java, tostring, superclass

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, I've searched through various questions but I don't think I'm geting any closer.

I have a superclass Vehicle that gives various details of a vehicle. I then have my Car class which inherits from Vehicle.

I am trying to print the toString from my Car class, which overides the Vehicle class.

Basically I want to print out the information about each car.

Here is my main

```
    public static void main(String []args)

    {

        Car Ford = new Car(Red, 4, true);

        //Ford = Ford.;   Tried various things here to no avail, kept getting nullfalse in output

        Car Honda = new Car(Blue, 4, false);


        System.out.println(Ford.vehicleDetails);

        System.out.println("Honda");

    }

}
```

This is my Vehicle class

```
public class Vehicle

{

// Variables

private String vehicleColour;

private int numberOfWheels;

String vehicleDetails;

// Constructor

public Vehicle(String vehicleColour, int numberOfWheels)

{

}

// Getters

public String getVehicleColour()

{
    return vehicleColour;
}

public int getNumberOfWheels()

{
    return numberOfWheels;
}



// Setters

public void setVehicleColour(String vehicleColour)

{
    this.vehicleColour = vehicleColour;
}


public void setNumberOfWheels(int numberOfWheels)

{
    this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
}


// Constructor

public Vehicle ()

{

}


// toString method super

public String toString() {

    String vehicleDetails = (getVehicleColour() + "" + getNumberOfWheels());

    return vehicleDetails;

}

}
```

And this is my Car class

```
    public class Car extends Vehicle

{

    // Variables

    private boolean convertible;

    Car vehicleDetails;

    // Getter

    public boolean getConvertible()

    {
        return convertible;
    }

    // Setter

    public void setConvertible(boolean convertible)

    {
        this.convertible = convertible;
    }

    // Constructor

    public Car(String vehicleColour, int numberOfWheels, boolean convertible) {


    }


        // toString method override

        @Override
        public String toString() {

        return super.toString() + convertible;

        }

    }
```

I want my output to be something like "The Ford is **red**, has **4** wheels and **is a convertible**", with bold text coming from Vehicle and Car classes respectively.

How do I get the bold text to show up in output? Right now I just get default values such as null, 0 and false.

I appreciate any input, I know I am probably doing something really stupid that is really obvious but I just can't see it.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, the code you gave us won't even compile.  In the `Vehicle` class, `vehicleColour` is defined as a String, but `getVehicleColour()` tries to return a double.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the post.

Comment: @Keeron can you please if my answer serves you right?

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam, you have answered far beyond my initial question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my output to be something like "The Ford is red, has 4 wheels and is a convertible"

For your above requirement simple solution:

```
System.out.println("The Ford is "+ Ford.toString() );
```

If you intend to get the whole output from `Ford.toString` then while creating `Ford` object you need to pass the *car name* too! Like shown below and make necessary changes in constructor for it!

```
Car Ford = new Car("Ford","Red", 4, true);
```

However constructors in `Car` and `Vehicle` class are made but no value is assigned to the local variables from them! Thus `.toString()` was not getting anything to show!

Required changes are:

**In Main Class**

```
System.out.println("The Ford is "+ Ford.toString() );
```

**In Car Class**

```
//change in the constructor
public Car(String vehicleColour, int numberOfWheels, boolean convertible) {

    setNumberOfWheels(numberOfWheels);
    setVehicleColour(vehicleColour);
    setConvertible(convertible);

}
```

> I am trying to print the toString from my Car class, which overides the Vehicle class.

```
//change in toString()


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(convertible){
             return super.toString() +"and is a convertible" ;
        }else{
             return super.toString() +"and is not a convertible" ;
        }


    }
```

**In Vehicle Class**

```
//change the constructor
public Vehicle(String vehicleColour, int numberOfWheels)

{
        setNumberOfWheels(this.numberOfWheels);
        setVehicleColour(this.vehicleColour);

}
```

> Basically I want to print out the information about each car.

```
//change the toString()
public String toString() {

    String vehicleDetails = (getVehicleColour() + ", has "  +getNumberOfWheels()+" wheels");

    return vehicleDetails;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed and informative response, I really appreciate it! I never even thought about setting values in the constructor class, I assumed that I could take values from the Strings, but obviously, since I was getting default values, I knew something wasn't right. Thanks again!

Comment: @Keeron its my pleasure to help you! Dont forget to give an upvote :p

Answer (score 0):

> I want my output to be something like "The Ford is red, has 4 wheels
>   and is a convertible", with bold text coming from Vehicle and Car
>   classes respectively.

If you want to include those words, then you have to tell it to include those words in your toString().

For example, if you want it to print "has 4 wheels", then you can't just do `getNumberOfWheels()`.  Otherwise you just get a 4.  You have to do something like `"has " + getNumberOfWheels() + " wheels"`.  If you don't tell it to include all the words, it won't know to include them.

Comment: Thanks DM, I can manage that part, I just wanted to give people an idea of what I want for the end result. Right now I get something like "The Ford is **null**, has **00** wheels and is a **false**".

Comment: Although you've created constructors that take parameters, those constructors don't seem to have any code in them to actually set the local variables to those parameters.  If you pass `numberOfWheels` into a constructor, that constructor should probably be setting `this.numberOfWheels` (or calling a `super` constructor you've made that does that.)

Comment: Thanks D M, I didn't realise I needed to set the values within the constructor, which, in hindsight, is rather obvious. I did say that I was probably doing something silly! thanks for all the help.